# Setting DatePicker Value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datepicker

I currently have a program that takes the value from a datePicker and have the date saved as a string. I only needed the date not the time so i used the following code to save the date value:

```
DateTime StartDate;
String inMyString;
savedDate = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
inMyString =   savedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

I have the `inMyString` pushedBack into my list and now i want to place it back into the datePicker.

On MSDN is shows me the following example to set the date.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2001, 10, 20);
```

the problem is that having .Value after my date picker is not an option (it doesn't show in Intellisense.)

I have also tried

```
datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value= new DateTime(inMyString)
```

and also converting the `inMyString` to type `DateTime` but it still does not work.

Any thoughts on how to do this?
Any Suggestions and comments are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
datePicker1.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2001, 10, 20);
```

If you need to take datetime from string:

```
datePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(inMyString);
```

---

Side note:

You can replace those 3 lines:

```
String inMyString;
savedDate = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
inMyString = savedDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

with one:

```
var inMyString = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

---

Another side note: don't know if there is a reason to it, but you might consider storing datetime as dattime, not as a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. Best answer I could of asked for and you even helped me reduce many lines of code. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show today's date in WPF C#, use this method:

```
datePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```