# Setting StringFormat of WPF DatePicker inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom WPF UserControl that uses a DatePicker within it. I'm setting the display format of the DatePicker using the answer provided [at this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398418/setting-datepicker-value)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePickerTextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yy', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to use a different format string for different instances of the control, so I'd like in some way to provide the format when I add the UserControl to the form, something like

```
<basecontrols:CustomControl 
    LabelWidth="{StaticResource LabelColumnWidth}" 
    Label="Custom Information" 
    DateDisplayFormat="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
    />
```

Label and LabelWidth are Dependancy properties of the custom UserControl.

Is it possible to have bind the StringFormat to a control property, when it is inside a Binding ? If not, is there a way to do what I want to do?

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have bind the `StringFormat` to a control property, when it is inside a `Binding` ?

No. You can't bind the `StringFormat` property of a `Binding` because it's not a dependency property.

What you could to is to define a `DateDisplayFormat` dependency property in your `CustomControl` (which I guess you have done already) and then override the `OnApplyTemplate` method and create the binding of the `TextBox` programmatically.

Alternatively, you could use a `<MultiBinding>` in the XAML markup that binds to both `SelectedDate` and `DateDisplayFormat` and use a multi converter that returns a `string`.

Comment: I've tried to use MultiBinding, and it works when I set the value from code. However, when I change the value using the DatePicker, it reverts to a standard dd/MM/yy date format. I do have a DateDisplayFormat dep property so I'll try that next

Comment: @IanBoggs: Your multi converter should be called whenever `SelectedDate` is set and you can then return whatever string you want.